# Last column gets oversized in jface

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

I'm quite new with Jface, and right now I'm facing a problem with the last column in a table. Take a look at the next screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the last column gets oversized when the application is initiated, and I can't fix that, no matter what! Below you can see the View code:

```
package de.vogella.jface.tableviewer;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ArrayContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnLabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewerColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;

import de.vogella.jface.tableviewer.model.CenterImageLabelProvider;
import de.vogella.jface.tableviewer.model.ModelProvider;
import de.vogella.jface.tableviewer.model.Person;

public class View extends ViewPart {

  public static final String ID = "de.vogella.jface.tableviewer.view";

  private TableViewer viewer;
  // static fields to hold the images
  private static final Image CHECKED = Activator.getImageDescriptor(
          "icons/checked.gif").createImage();
  private static final Image UNCHECKED = Activator.getImageDescriptor(
          "icons/unchecked.gif").createImage();

  public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false);
    parent.setLayout(layout);
    Label searchLabel = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
    searchLabel.setText("Search: ");
    final Text searchText = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SEARCH);
    searchText.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.GRAB_HORIZONTAL
        | GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL));
    createViewer(parent);
  }

  private void createViewer(Composite parent) {

    viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
        | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
    createColumns(parent, viewer);
    final Table table = viewer.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
    // get the content for the viewer, setInput will call getElements in the
    // contentProvider
    viewer.setInput(ModelProvider.INSTANCE.getPersons());
    // make the selection available to other views
    getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);
    // set the sorter for the table

    // define layout for the viewer
    GridData gridData = new GridData();
    gridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
    gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
    gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
    gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
    viewer.getControl().setLayoutData(gridData);
  }

  public TableViewer getViewer() {

    return viewer;
  }

  // create the columns for the table
  private void createColumns(final Composite parent, final TableViewer viewer) {

    String[] titles = { "First name", "Last name", "Gender", "Married", "Age" };
    int[] bounds = { 100, 100, 100, 100, 100 };

    // first column is for the first name
    TableViewerColumn col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[0], bounds[0], 0);
    col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {

      @Override
      public String getText(Object element) {

        Person p = (Person) element;

        return p.getFirstName();
      }
    });

    // second column is for the last name
    col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[1], bounds[1], 1);
    col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {

      @Override
      public String getText(Object element) {

        Person p = (Person) element;

        return p.getLastName();
      }
    });

    // now the gender
    col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[2], bounds[2], 2);
    col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {

      @Override
      public String getText(Object element) {

        Person p = (Person) element;

        return p.getGender();
      }
    });

    // now the status married
    col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[3], bounds[3], 3);
    col.setLabelProvider(new CenterImageLabelProvider() {

      @Override
      public Image getImage(Object element) {

        if (((Person) element).isMarried()) {

          return CHECKED;
        }
        else {

          return UNCHECKED;
        }
      }
    });

    // now the age
    col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[4], bounds[4], 4);
    col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {

      @Override
      public String getText(Object element) {

          Person p = (Person) element;

          return p.getAge().toString();
      }
    });

  }

  private TableViewerColumn createTableViewerColumn(String title, 
          int bound, final int colNumber) {

    final TableViewerColumn viewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer,
        SWT.CENTER);
    final TableColumn column = viewerColumn.getColumn();
    column.setText(title);
    column.setWidth(bound);
    column.setResizable(true);
    column.setMoveable(true);

    return viewerColumn;
  }

  public void setFocus() {

    viewer.getControl().setFocus();
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your layout on the viewer:

```
GridData gridData = new GridData();
gridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
viewer.getControl().setLayoutData(gridData);
```

says that you want the viewer to use all the available horizontal space, so the viewer has had to resize the last column to make this happen.

Use

```
gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = false;
gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.BEGINNING;
```

to not grab the extra space.

Alternatively to fill the space available leave the GridData alone and use `TableLayout` and `ColumnWeightData`, something like:

```
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout();
table.setLayout(tableLayout);

...
... don't call column.setWidth replace with:
tableLayout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(nnn));
```

`nnn` is a number you choose for each column and is the 'weight' used to calculate the width of the column.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping and for the explanation! It's still a bit "ugly", because the window is much bigger than the data. Do you know how can I fix this? And in your opinion, am I following the most appropriate approach?

Comment: Added usage of TableLayout